# Как обнулить элементы массива,кроме максимального?

Tags: javascript

```js
let arr = [16, -37, 54, -4, 72, -56, 47, 4, -16, 25, -37, 46, 4, -51, 27, -63, 4, -54, 76, -4, 12, -35, 4, 47];
let max = arr[0];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] > max) {
    max = arr[i];
  }

  if (arr[i] !== max) {
    arr[i] = 0;
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Вроде написал правильно,но обнуляет не все значения

Answer (score 3):

На каждой итерации есть два элемента: максимальный и текущий.

Условие должно быть простое: если текущий элемент больше максимального - обнуляем максимальный, если меньше - обнуляем текущий.

Для обнуления максимального - нужно хранить индекс максимального элемента

Тогда условие может быть таким

```
if (arr[i] > max) {
    max = arr[i];
    arr[maxi] = 0;
    maxi = i;
} else {
    arr[i] = 0;
}
```

В дополнении, проверку можно начинать со второго элемента, либо проверить, что i не совпадает с maxi - иначе обнулятся все элементы.

Пример:

```js
let arr = [167, -37, 54, -4, 72, -56, 47, 4, -16, 25, -37, 46, 4, -51, 27, -63, 4, -54, 76, -4, 12, -35, 4, 47];
let max = arr[0];
let maxi = 0;
for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] > max) {
    max = arr[i];
    arr[maxi] = 0;
    maxi = i;
  } else {
    arr[i] = 0;
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Либо начальное значение для максимального элемента указать минимальным:

```js
let arr = [167, -37, 54, -4, 72, -56, 47, 4, -16, 25, -37, 46, 4, -51, 27, -63, 4, -54, 76, -4, 12, -35, 4, 47];
let max = -Infinity;
let maxi = -1;
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] > max) {
    max = arr[i];
    if (maxi > -1)
      arr[maxi] = 0;
    maxi = i;
  } else {
    arr[i] = 0;
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: маленький недочет в случае максимального первого элемента

Comment: @Igor, уже поправил :) и дописал пояснение

Comment: О, точно. *(6 символов нужно...)*

Comment: arr[i] >= max
Поправил и получилось,спасибо

Comment: @IhorStoner, `arr[i] >= max` - не поможет, если максимальный элемент нулевой. От строгости проверки зависит только первый из максимальных элементов останется или последний.

Comment: @Grundy, Можно последний вопрос. Что делает эта строчка arr[maxi] = 0;Сорян,понял

Comment: @IhorStoner. зануляет элемент, который был максимальным, в случае если текущий элемент больше

Answer (score 2):

Можно в процессе сохранять индекс и значение максимального элемента и без разбора всё обнулять. А в конце перебора сделать одну вставку)

```js
let arr = [16, -37, 54, -4, 72, -56, 47, 4, -16, 25, -37, 46, 4, -51, 27, -63, 4, -54, 76, -4, 12, -35, 4, 47];

let max = {n: arr[0], i: 0};
for( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
  if( arr[i] > max.n ) max = {n: arr[i], i: i};
  arr[i] = 0;
}
arr[ max.i ] = max.n;

console.log( JSON.stringify(arr) );
```

Comment: Остроумно. *(5 символов нужно...)*

Comment: Я думал, когда же уже добавят самый очевидный вариант)

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ это перебрать массив еще раз с условием, если число не равняется максимальному, обнулить. Пример:

```
let arr =  [16,-37,54,-4,72,-56,47,4,-16,25,-37,46,4,-51,27,-63,4,-54,76,-4,12,-35,4,47];
let max = arr[0];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > max) {
        max = arr[i];
    }
}

let res = arr.map(val => max !== val ? 0 : val);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: так пишите, как будто существует способ сделать это не перебирая массив второй раз

Comment: if (arr[i] != max) {
        arr[i] = 0;
    }
Почему обнуляет не все значения?

Comment: @teran, ну извращения всякие бывают. Например: Сохранять индекс существующего числа и создать новый массив с нулями и поместить туда максимально число.

Comment: @Ihor Stoner, в Вашем случае все зависит, где вставляете. Нужно для этого второй цикл

Comment: @teran. по идее можно за один проход все

Comment: [16, 0, 54, 0, 72, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 76, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Результат

Comment: @Grundy всего с  одним единственным циклом? - показывай.

Comment: @IhorStoner, используйте мой вариант, он рабочий. Или вылаживайте код целиком

Answer (score 0):

альтернативный вариант с функциями, если пригодится

```js
let arr =  [16,-37,54,-4,72,-56,47,4,-16,25,-37,46,4,-51,27,-63,4,-54,76,-4,12,-35,4,47];

const max = Math.max(...arr);
const result = arr.map(v => v == max ? v : 0);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Пока не дошел до функций

Comment: if (arr[i] != max) {
        arr[i] = 0;
    }
Почему обнуляет не все значения?

Comment: @IhorStoner потому что вы идете по массиву и сравниваете с максимумом не всего массива, а только предыдущих элементов.